# Movies and TV Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

**Note:** This evaluation will close on **12 October 2012**. Be sure to get your votes in by then!

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 9):

[Is the "Pin number cracking" scene in Terminator 2 a plot hole?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3870/is-the-pin-number-cracking-scene-in-terminator-2-a-plot-hole)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: good question, excellent answer

Comment: Question is great, provides a lot of background and detail and the answer accomplishes the same.

Comment: Well plot hole questions are not the greatest (see http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53/yes-that-was-a-plot-hole-and ) but as they go this is a great answer.

Comment: I think this is more of plot-hole question, which I'm not that fond of. Of course computers are used for weird awesome things in movies and the script writers probably didn't think that thoroughly about it. But I also have to say that this is one of the better examples of this kind of questions and it got some really good and insightful answers.

Answer (score 8):

[Who hired Malcolm Crowe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/who-hired-malcolm-crowe)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Great question that pushes the reader to think about an  ordinary detail that is overlooked by many spectators.  Answer provides a great summary of the answer and proper background.

Comment: Quite an interresting question being IMHO a bit more than a simple plot-hole question. And a good answer, too.

Answer (score 4):

[Why does Tommy wear a hockey mask in the end of Friday the 13th: A New Beginning?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/why-does-tommy-wear-a-hockey-mask-in-the-end-of-friday-the-13tha-new-beginning)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Question is good and the answers are good.  Generic quality question.  Nothing wrong with it, but nothing spectacular.

Comment: Good question and one of the better examples of a self-answer (reached through further research after posting the question).

Answer (score 4):

[Why did Jigsaw choose Zep in Saw?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/why-did-jigsaw-choose-zep-in-saw)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: good question, good answer

Comment: Interesting question that allows you to think a bit deeper behind the main villains motives.  Answer provides enough detail and references to answer question.

Comment: That is the question what i also what to ask.

Comment: Good plot-explanation question with a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Identify a Horror film about bees which convert human into zombies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3953/identify-a-horror-film-about-bees-which-convert-human-into-zombies)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Identify question.  Good detail, good answer.

Comment: Identify that gets the basics down (detail) and answer as well.

Comment: A good example of an identification question.

Comment: I got good answer for this question

Comment: Well, I'm not totally decided on the value of identify questions yet, even if asking and answering them. But this one is not bad and it got a good explanative answer.

Answer (score 2):

[What is the book that Emile Hirsch reads in "Into the Wild"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/what-is-the-book-that-emile-hirsch-reads-in-into-the-wild)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Question borders on Trivia but the answer is a great summary of the answers.

Comment: Trivia question with an excellent answer

Comment: Hmm, the question sounds rather trivial (and the *analysis* tag is quite a shame, though some more explanation in which way this was interresting for the rest of the movie, would have helped (haven't seen it, though). But the answer is really detailed.

Answer (score 1):

[Trying to find a film with a political joke about pot and california](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/trying-to-find-a-film-with-a-political-joke-about-pot-and-california)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Identify question that depends on a single line of dialogue to figure out its answer.  Answerer does recognize the movie and correctly answers.

Comment: Well, another identify question, and with a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[What does the title of The Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie mean, especially the Discreet Charm part?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/what-does-the-title-of-the-discreet-charm-of-the-bourgeoisie-mean-especially-th)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Judging solely on the fact the director is a surrealist, the question is great material but the answer is lacking at best and only provides information for one apsect of the question.

Comment: As community we do not do well with non-mainstream movies.  This is an example of that.  The answer is not great.

Comment: I agree with iandotkelly, ti's not a bad question, it just isn't main stream so it's not getting a lot of love.  would love to see a real answer for this.

Comment: Having not seen the movie, the question, even if seeming like a mere word explanation at first, actually offers great possibilites for extensive analysis and interpretation, though not used by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Why doesn't Bruce take a running jump when trying to escape from the pit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3879/why-doesnt-bruce-take-a-running-jump-when-trying-to-escape-from-the-pit)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Interesting question about mechanics in a movie, answer provides enough detail to be useful.

Comment: Interesting question - answer not convincing, but the comment about the curvature of the wall does help it.

Comment: I'm sort of meh on this question.

Comment: For me this question isn't really much more than a mere plot-hole question (in the sense that I don't think there's any deeper reason for the described indcident). And I totally disagree with the answer, even if judged by objective criteria it's not that bad an answer.

Answer (score -4):

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/doctor-who-and-the-2012-olympic-games

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Not a fan of it at all.

Comment: 3 close votes says it all.  Really this might be off topic ... since it relates to current affairs more than Dr. Who.

Comment: I closed it as off-topic.  It wasn't about the tv show at all but rather the olympics and the appearance of a show in current affairs.

Comment: to a point this was a valid question. Dr. Who is not just a TV Show; it's an important part of british culture. Therefore it is totally okay to ask, why this show wasn't featured in the olympics opening when other british shows/higlights got huge spots (mr. bean, queen etc).

Comment: @oers as far as i can tell questions about culture pertaining to movies is still off-topic for the site.  As i said in the comment i left, it can be brought up on meta for everyone to discuss and come to a concensus.

Comment: For me this is off-topic (being the first close-voter on it) for exactly the reasons *DForck42* describes. But it even got a good answer if disregarding the off-topicness of the whole thread.