# Can one view the analytics for a site?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few images attached to posts here on Stackexchange.

[image: Stats]

Where are these from? and is it possible for anyone to view this data?

EDIT:

Here is where I've seen these.

[How come Movies and TV is still in beta?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/how-come-movies-and-tv-is-still-in-beta)

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/

Comment: Where'd you get that?

Comment: @DForck42 http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/754/69

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those graphs are part of an internal toolset we use to analyze the overall health and trends of a site. But specific analytics data is intended for internal use only and the raw data is not generally shared with the public.

On occasion, I will [post a somewhat-sanitized graph](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/754/69) of the data like that to illustrate a larger point, like how a site is trending in its overall growth or whatever is being discussed. But *no*, it is not possible to view this data.

Answer (score 4):

One source of information is quantcast: http://www.quantcast.com/movies.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

As @DForck42 mentioned, its possible to peek at this stuff using Quantcast.

The view you have there is a Secret-Super-Special-Awesome-Mod-Power not available to normal users and only to ♦ Moderators.

Comment: +1 for using Secret-Super-Special-Awesome-Mod-Power in an answer.