# Isn't it time for us to be official?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come Movies and TV is still in beta?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/how-come-movies-and-tv-is-still-in-beta)

I'm wondering why [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) is still in Beta and so plain-looking.
It's doing fairly well and it's been up for a long time.
Shouldn't it be redesigned by now?

Comment: Read robert's answer to the mentioned question.